# nvd3 chart inside ngx-datatable binding issue

Tags: angular, nvd3.js, ngx-datatable

I am trying to get `nvd3` chart inside `ngx-datatable` expand collapse. But it is not initializing the graph on `ngOnInit`.

`nvd3` graph and `ngx-datatable` are in different components. The graph has huge data and it is loading only on mouse trigger but not on `ngOnInit`.

Comment: Please update your question with what you have done so far(some code maybe), what problems you are facing currently. The more information you provide the higher chances of you getting some help